# How to initialize mimetypes library in AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, mime-types

mimetypes does not recognize files like the following: xlsx, docx, etc., so I want to initialize my mime_types.txt file so that it can recognize those file types.

I know you need to initialize the library with the path of my mime_types.txt with the additional extensions, but it is still returning "None" for the mime-type, which I am assuming to mean that I'm not initializing the mimetypes library properly.

How do I accomplish this in AWS lambda? I am trying to do this without storing the text file with the additional extensions locally as I'm worried that it won't work outside of my PC then.

Right now, I have my mime_types.txt file stored in an s3 bucket, and I have been trying to initialize mimetypes like so:

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.init("s3://mybucketname/mime_types.txt")
mime_type= mimetypes.guess_type("randomFile.xlsx")
print(mime_type)
```

I have also tried

```
mimetypes.init(["s3://mybucketname/mime_types.txt"])
and
mimetypes.init(s3://mybucketname/mime_types.txt)
```

They all return "None" for mime_type, so I'm not sure what's going wrong or if what I'm attempting is possible. Thank you for any help!